# Sass, Compass and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sass, compass-sass

Can't find information about JavaScript usage with Compass, in configuration i found an "javascript_dir" options, but dont know how to use it.
Can somebody please explain for what this option is here, and how to use it with .scss files?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't interact with Sass in any meaningful way.  Modules *can* provide JS files as part of their package:  http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment above is correct, Compass and Sass don't normally interact with JS. It is possible for someone to include JS in a compass plugin, in which case Compass needs to know where those files should go when you install the plugin. That's the only use for the "javascript_dir" at this point. If you aren't installing any plugins with JS, you can ignore it.